# Help solving an Elliptic Integral

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals, elliptic-integrals

I am facing an elliptic integral to solve during thesis, however, I'm having a lot of trouble trying to solve it. The integral is given by:
$$\int{\frac{\sin^2(\theta)}{\sqrt{1+B\sin^2(\theta)}}}d\theta$$
where $B$ is a constant. I've been trying to use the Byrd and Friedman's Handbook but could not figure out some transformations that he adopts throughout the book. Any help provided will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This exact integral is B&F 310.02. The DLMF uses the special notation $D(\varphi,m)$ for this integral - what you have here would be $D(\varphi,-B)$ - because it can be calculated with one Carlson symmetric form, skipping a subtraction.

Comment: Thank you, Parcly. I was adopting this approach but couldn't figure out how to solve the Carlson elliptic integral $R_F$ analytically. The original elliptic integral I'm struggling with arises from a non-linear ODE, and at this point, I would prefer not to use a numerical approximation.

Comment: It is an _elliptic integral_! A transcendental one, which cannot be analytically derived from elementary functions. In fact the Carlson forms are the modern way of evaluating them - they use this thing called a duplication theorem, which is like an AGM for three or four variables, to achieve their speed.

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac{\sin^2(\theta)}{\sqrt{1+B\sin^2(\theta)}}=\frac{\sqrt{B \sin ^2(\theta )+1}}{B}-\frac{1}{B \sqrt{B \sin ^2(\theta )+1}}$$
$$\int{\frac{\sin^2(\theta)}{\sqrt{1+B\sin^2(\theta)}}}d\theta=\frac{E(\theta |-B)-F(\theta |-B)}{B}$$

Comment: Thank you, Claude. Is it possible to solve the incomplete elliptic integrals analytically?

Comment: @MateusForcelini. What to you mean by *"to solve" ? Do you want approximations ?

Comment: I mean to obtain a closed-form solution for the integral

Comment: @MateusForcelini. I do not understand : this is a closed form (not to say **the** closed form). Could you precise ?

Comment: I mean that don't need a numerical method to evaluate it